# What's problem with this pagination code?

Tags: python, flask, pagination

This code already have done the pagination ,but it false because per page it shows all items in the database ,and the same in other pages

This is the routing

```
@app.route('/shop/page/<int:page_num>')

def shop(page_num):
    products=Product.query.filter
                    (Product.category.has(Product.category_id))
    shopPage=Product.query.paginate
                     (page=page_num,per_page=5,error_out=True)
    return render_template('shop.html',
                     shopPage=shopPage,products=products)
```

And this is the HTML code of pagination and the output products of database

```
{% block content %}

   <div class="mb-5">
    {% for product in products %}

    <div class="col-4 mt-3 ">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('shop') }}" >
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{product.name }}</h5>  
                    <p class="card-text"> 
                        <div>Category: {{ product.category.name }}</div>
                        <div>Price: {{ product.price }} $</div>
                        <div>Company:  {{ product.company }}</div>
                    </p>
                </div>       

            </div>    

        </div>


 {% endfor %}


</div>        

 {% for page in shopPage.iter_pages(left_edge=2, right_edge=2, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}

        {% if page %}
        <nav >
                <ul class="pagination ">
                  <li class="page-item ">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{url_for('shop',page_num=page)}}"  tabindex="-1">{{ page }}</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
        </nav>

        {% else %}
                ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are always rendering the items from the `products` query while the `shopPage` query is the one that is paginated (but not filtered). So basically, you have two independent sets of products there: One filtered, one paginated. You are displaying the items from the former but the pagination for the latter.

Comment: I understand You,but can't correct code.
What advice can You do?

Comment: Basically, drop the `products` from the function and the view, and instead of iterating over the `products`, iterate over the items in `shopPage.items`.